# In python I am trying to match two dataframes flows such that I know how much is left over?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, numpy

```
cheese_received = pd.Dataframe(data=[[1, 30, 50], [3, 50, 20]], columns=['Cheese Quality Level', 'Cheese Amount UK', 'Cheese Amount French'])
cheese_sent = pd.Dataframe(data=[[2, 60, 30], [3, 10, 10]], columns=['Cheese Quality Level', 'Cheese Amount UK', 'Cheese Amount French'])
```

From the dataframes above for each UK and france I want to produce a dataframe that looks like the one below. However I can't create a system which does the following:The outflows and inflows are calculated based on a comparison system that compares from the worst quality to the best quality:

Level 3 sent vs Level 3 received

Level 3 sent vs Level 2 received

Level 3 sent vs Level 1 received

Level 2 sent vs Level 3 received

Level 2 sent vs Level 2 received

Level 2 sent vs Level 1 received

Level 1 sent vs Level 3 received

Level 1 sent vs Level 2 received

Level 1 sent vs Level 1 received

Then how flows are calculated is if quality of cheese is Level 3 vs Level 3 then no outflows or inflows. If the quality of cheese sent is better than the quality received we see an inflow and vice versa for an outflow. E.g. if Level 2 sent vs Level 3 received we see an inflow, and level 2 sent vs level 1 received produces an outflow. The size of the outflow or inflow is the notional multiplied by the multiplier for the cheese quality difference. Anything left over is simply the notional in that direction. (outflow for received, inflow for sent)

Level 1 vs Level 3 : Notional * 0.5

Level 1 vs Level 2: Notional * 0.25

Level 3 vs Level 2: Notional * 0.15

Level x vs Level x (where x=x): 0

So for example for UK cheese the output we want is:

```
|Lvl Sent|Level Received|Sent  |Received|Outflow|Inflow |
|:------:|:------------:|:----:|:------:|:-----:|:-----:|
|   3    |       3      | 10   |  10    | 0     |  0    |
|   2    |       3      | 40   |  40    | 0     |40*0.15|
|   2    |       1      | 20   |  20    |20*0.25|  0    |
|   1    |       1      |  0   |  10    | 10    |  0    |
```

If anyone can help me implement an algorithm or a step in the right direction I would be very grateful. I am also looking for a function that expands to more than 3 levels?

Comment: needs a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @GoldenLion The lvl comes from the cheese quality level in the initial dataframe. I have updated the desired result to represent this more clearly

Comment: how is level received determined? are you joining by row id the sent and received columns accounting for sent 2 and received 3 and sent 3 and received 3.  how are the other combinations determined

Comment: @GoldenLion Level received is given in the cheese_recevied dataframe. How we determine the combinations are based on the comparison system I have included. We compare sent vs received of the worst quality of both to start. Whichever sent or received has more left over is then compared to the next level. If the notionals match we simply move again to the lower (better quality) level and compare like this until there is a remaining notional sent or notional received, calculating at each comparison an inflow or an outflow